# Sqlite foreign key reverse cascade delete

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, foreign-keys, android-room

I have two tables movies and songs. songs have the foreign key in movies. I need to delete the movie entry when all the songs referenced to the movie is deleted. just like reverse cascade like many to one.

when deleting song entries if all the songs will be deleted the movie should be delete.

how can I achive this on sqlite simply like cascade delete..?

- List item

Answer (score 0):

An `AFTER DELETE` [trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) works. Example sqlite3 shell session:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE movies(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE songs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name, movie_id INTEGER REFERENCES movies(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
sqlite> CREATE INDEX songs_movie_id_idx ON songs(movie_id);
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER cleanup_movies AFTER DELETE ON songs WHEN ((SELECT count(*) FROM songs WHERE movie_id=old.movie_id) = 0) BEGIN DELETE FROM movies WHERE id = old.movie_id; END;
sqlite> INSERT INTO movie VALUES (1, 'Some Movie');
sqlite> INSERT INTO song VALUES (1, 'Some Song', 1), (2, 'Some Other Song', 1);
sqlite> DELETE FROM songs WHERE id = 1;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM movies;
id          name      
----------  ----------
1           Some Movie
sqlite> DELETE FROM songs WHERE id = 2;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM movies;
sqlite>
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cleanup_movies AFTER DELETE ON songs
WHEN ((SELECT count(*) FROM songs WHERE movie_id=old.movie_id) = 0)
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM movies WHERE id = old.movie_id;
END;
```

After deleting a row from `songs`, if there are no more rows in the `songs` table with the same `movie_id` as the deleted row, delete that id from the `movies` table.